# Convert char array to string use C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to convert a char array to string.
Something like this:

```
char array[20];
char string[100];

array[0]='1';
array[1]='7';
array[2]='8';
array[3]='.';
array[4]='9';
...
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
char string[0]= array // where it was stored 178.9 ....in position [0]
```

Comment: read man atof, man strtod

Comment: What do you mean "a char array to a string", a char array is a string.

Comment: @Mike If and only if there appears a '\0' within the object.

Comment: char string[100] should probably be a char string[100][N]

Comment: I know that '\0' is the terminating character, but I need to save the 10 elements of the whole char array to string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're saying you have this:

```
char array[20]; char string[100];
array[0]='1'; 
array[1]='7'; 
array[2]='8'; 
array[3]='.'; 
array[4]='9';
```

And you'd like to have this:

```
string[0]= "178.9"; // where it was stored 178.9 ....in position [0]
```

You can't have that. A char holds 1 character. That's it. 
A "string" in C is an array of characters followed by a sentinel character (NULL terminator).

Now if you want to copy the first x characters out of `array` to `string` you can do that with `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(string, array, x);
string[x] = '\0';
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have 15 reputation to do so I can Data thumb :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `array` is a character array that does not end in `\0`, you will want to use `strncpy`:

```
char * strncpy(char * destination, const char * source, size_t num);
```

like so:

```
strncpy(string, array, 20);
string[20] = '\0'
```

Then `string` will be a null terminated C string, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strcpy` but remember to end the array with `'\0'`

```
char array[20]; char string[100];

array[0]='1'; array[1]='7'; array[2]='8'; array[3]='.'; array[4]='9'; array[5]='\0';
strcpy(string, array);
printf("%s\n", string);
```