# How to concatenate an array of chars into 1 variable?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have an array of chars that I would like to set to 1 variable. How would I go about doing this. For example I would have the following code:

```
char list[5] = {'B','O','B','B','Y'};
```

how would I have it so that I could set it to a variable to have it so that:

```
char *name = "BOBBY"
```

pulling the values from the list shown above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char array to string use C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344130/convert-char-array-to-string-use-c)

Comment: `char *name = strndup(list, sizeof(list));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, there is a simpler solution for systems conforming to POSIX 1-2008, such as linux and OS/X:

```
char *name = strndup(list, sizeof(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the string is not null terminated you cannot assume that functions like `strcpy` will succeed - you will need to do something in O(n) that copies each character one by one:

```
char *str = NULL;
int len_orig = sizeof(list);
int i;

str = malloc(len_orig+1);
if(!str)
{
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(i = 0; i < len_orig; i++)
{
    str[i] = list[i];
}
str[len_orig]=0;

// use str...

free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6); // 6 because 5 + 1 for null terminator
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    temp[i] = list[i];
temp[5] = '\0';
```

You can do this, I'd not use `strcpy` for this as your array is not null-terminated.