# Problem to create char based on buffer and length in kernel module

Tags: c, kernel-module

I try to get strings from userspace within the kernel module. Till I set my char size manually it seems working properly. However, I need to make it dynamic so if I use `len` parameter it shows weird symbols on the end of char.

```
static ssize_t msecurity_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
  
    char chars[12];
    if(copy_from_user(chars,buffer,len)){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Output> %s", chars);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "lengh> %i", len);

    return len;
 
}
```

First output is for `char[len]` secound has been set manualy `char[12]`. Even if you print `len` it shows value of 12.

[image: console output for debug]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert char array to string use C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344130/convert-char-array-to-string-use-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C strings are terminated by a `null` character. This character is not included in any string length calculation but must be included.

Thus a string of length 12 will need 13 bytes with the last byte equal to 0.