# Convert string to time_t in c

Tags: c, date, casting

Hi I need to convert the variable `time`, containing a string to a time_t type with the format i would like to print after:

```
   time_t t = time(NULL);
   struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
   char time[100];
   strftime(time, 100, "%b %d %H:%M", tm);
```

I wouldn't like to make any modifications in the code above and keep the format I chose. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is what you mean, but I think you need to use `strptime` and `mktime`.

Comment: In order to convert an array to a string see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344130/convert-char-array-to-string-use-c

Comment: You shouldn't declare variables or functions with the same name as system functions.  Other that that, this should work.

Comment: I have edited the question, forgot to tell you i wanted to cast to time_t XD

Comment: @DanielRodriguez Is code limited to standard C functions or are extensions like `strptime()` usable?

Comment: The goal here has _nothing_ to do with _cast_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the non-standard C function [strptime()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) allowed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Return -1 on error
time_t DR_string_to_time(const char *s) {
  // Get current year
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  if (t == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  struct tm *now = localtime(&t);
  if (now == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Assume current year
  struct tm DR_time = {.tm_year = now->tm_year, .tm_isdst = -1}; 
  if (strptime(s, "%b %d %H:%M", &DR_time) == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  t = mktime(&DR_time);
  return t;
}
```

Note: `"%b %d %H:%M"` (month, day, hour, minute) does not contain the *year*, so code needs some year to form a `time_t`.